# .Net Framework 2.0 SP2 requirements?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

I've been searching this topic for the last couple of days and I can't find an answer yet.

Do I need .Net Framework 1.0 or 2.0 to install 2.0 SP2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [.NET Framework 2.0 SP2 download on MS site](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1639) includes .NET Framework 2.0, so to answer your question you don't need *either* 1.0 or 2.0 to install this.